# Several Buttons with EventListeners, and ONE isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have several Buttons that can be shown and that trigger JavaScript EventListeners. All of them have worked fine so far, but the latest one i have added somehow doesn't work. Tham means the Listener isn't called at all.
I ran out of ideas and hope you can find what i am missing...

The "collective" Button is the one that isn't working...

Javascript:

```
var rid = document.getElementById("rid").value;
var clearButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=clear]");
var saveButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=save]");
var collectiveButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=collective]");
var discardButton = document.querySelector("[data-action=discard]");

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});


saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Bitte geben Sie erst eine Unterschrift ein.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    //alert("RID: " + rid + "DataURL:" + dataURL);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../system.php",
      data: {
         imgBase64: dataURL,
         rid: rid,
         SaveSignature: true
      }
    })
    .always(function() {
    window.location.href = '../system.php?site=createreports&success=true';
  });
  }
});

discardButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../system.php",
      data: {
         rid: rid,
         DeleteReport: true
      }
    })
    .always(function() {
    window.location.href = '../system.php?site=createreports&success=discard';
  });
});


collectiveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Bitte geben Sie erst eine Unterschrift ein.");
  } else {
    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    //alert("RID: " + rid + "DataURL:" + dataURL);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../system.php",
      data: {
         imgBase64: dataURL,
         rid: rid,
         SaveCollectiveSignature: true
      }
    })
    .always(function() {
    window.location.href = '../system.php?site=createreports&success=true';
  });
  }
});
```

The HTML-part:

```
<div class="row vdivide">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <input type="hidden" name="rid" id="rid" value="31">
        <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
            <div class="signature-pad--body">
                <canvas></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row vdivide">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"></div>
</div>
<div class="row vdivide">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-action="clear">Neu anfangen</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-action="save">Speichern einzeln</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-action="collective">Speichern alles</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're positive the handler isn't getting called?  Put a `console.log('here')` as the first line of the handler.  Do you see the message logged to the console?  Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: You don't have a `discardButton`, the code is failing at that point and the event listener doesn't get applied to the `collectiveButton` which comes after it. If you looked at the developer console you should have seen an error... `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` because `discardButton` is `null`.

Comment: Oh i see. What buttons actually appear depens on several things... so what i need is some kind of "do XYZ only if object exists", right?

Comment: Maybe `if (typeof maybeObject != "undefined") { ... }` around all the listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the developer console you should see an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

This is because there is no button with `data-action=discard` in your HTML, so the statement `document.querySelector("[data-action=discard]")` returns `null`.

When your code tries to assign an event listener to `discardButton` (which is `null`) it throws the error, and the code stops, which means the code to add an event listener to `collectiveButton` is not executed.

If the HTML is conditional, you will need to check if the button exists before trying to add an event listener to it. Something as simple as this:

```
if (discardButton) {
  discardButton.addEventListener(...
}
```

Comment: Here's what i did: I added additional Variables with Booleans depending on the elements existance:
`var discardButtonExist = document.querySelector("[data-action=discard]") !== null;`
And then i wrapped the Adding of the Listeners into `if (discardButtonExist) { ... }`
Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MarcelLehmann That way will work, but there really isn't any need for the extra variables when you can just check the variable you already have to see if it is null.

Comment: I'm pretty new into JavaScript and have yet to learn that it is way more comfortable then the language i had to work with the last years (C). There an if does always require a boolean, and you wouldn't be able to check the existance of something just by putting the object itself into an if ^^

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure C if statements are based on whether the value is non-zero, not actual boolean types. But in any case, in JavaScript all values are either ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or "falsy". `null` is a falsy value, so checking for null is as simple as just putting the variable in an if statement (with a few exceptions, like if you have an empty string or a numerical `0`).

Answer (score 0):

As @Herohtar said you should wrap the addEventListener function in if statement to check if not null. 
I would use a sort of helper function like this one here if I'm going to show the buttons conditionally :

```js
function addClickEvent(button , func){
  if(button){
    button.addEventListener('click',func);
  }else{
    console.error('Button doesn\'t exist ');
  }
};
```